# Java 8 Update 20 Missing security options

Tags: java, security, applet, missing-features

I have Java 8 update 20 and I just made my first applet, but when I try to run it in the browser it says that my security settings have blocked it! After I go into my java settings and go in the security tab all I see it:

Enable Java content in the browser (It is a checkbox)
Security level for applications not on the Exception site list
Very high (RADIO BUTTON)
High (RADIO BUTTON)

And then I have my exception site list...
I am missing the Medium radio button? I can't run my applet without the medium option! I have tried adding my site to the exceptions list but it didn't work...
I have deinstalled the previous version of java which was Java 8 update 11.
What's the problem???
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question;

> ```
> I am missing the Medium radio button? ... What's the problem?
> ```

Correct. You are missing the Medium radio button now. To quote the [8u20 release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u20-relnotes-2257729.html)

> **Java Control Panel Changes**
>
> The Update tab in the Java Control Panel now enables the users to automatically update 64-bit JREs (in addition to 32-bit versions) that are installed on their system.
>
> The `Medium` security level has been removed. Now only `High` and `Very High` levels are available.

You can develop with an applet viewer; you'll need to sign your code for security reasons.

**Edit**

From [Deploying an Applet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/deployingApplet.html) (The Java Tutorials) -

> To deploy your Java applet, first compile the source code, package it as a JAR file, and sign the JAR file.

See [Signing JAR Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signing.html) for how to sign your Applet.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I sign my code? I have uploaded the applet to the internet so me and my friend can test it out since it's a multiplayer game...

Comment: Hi, 1 more question, keytool is not a valid command? I have java jdk installed whats the problem?

Comment: @Mateo226 My link says `jarsigner`. Where do you see `keytool`?

Comment: Sorry, thanks for you help, will do some more google-ing now :)